# How to check if childnode of Javascript object contains array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working with xml parsed as JSON. In a specific situation, if a node contains several childnodes the childnodes are stored in an array. If a node contains 1 childnode it's not stored in an array. I need to be able to check if the childnodes are in an array or not. How can I do this?

Example:

no array:

```
"parentnode":
{
    "childnode1":
    {
        "childnode1.1":
        {
            "childnode1.1.1":"value here",
        },
    },
}
```

with array:

```
"parentnode":
{
    "childnode1":
    [
        {
            "childnode1.1":
            {
                "childnode1.1.1":"value here",
            },
        },
        {
            "childnode1.2":
            {
                "childnode1.2.1":"value here",
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

In the 'no array' example, you can see that childnode1 does not contain an array. In the 'with array' example, childnode1 contains an array with multiple childnodes (1.1 and 1.2).

I tried counting childnodes with

```
var counter=0;
for(child in childnode1)
{ counter++; }
```

however this generates unexpected results, for example counter is not '1' when there is no array. Any solutions?

Comment: check out [`Array.isArray(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray). Note that you are dealing with plain JavaScript objects. Don't call that JSON. Reserve that term for the text representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest check would be simply to use [`Array.isArray(targetnode)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) as noted by trincot.

Using something like .length could would work (with assumptions that nodes are always either an object or an array), but it would be less robust and not as readable.

```js
// no array
var object1 = {
  "parentnode":
  {
    "childnode1":
    {
        "childnode1.1":
        {
            "childnode1.1.1":"value here",
        },
    },
  }
};

// has array
var object2 = {
  "parentnode":
  {
    "childnode1":
    [
        {
            "childnode1.1":
            {
                "childnode1.1.1":"value here",
            },
        },
        {
            "childnode1.2":
            {
                "childnode1.2.1":"value here",
            }
        },
    ]
  }
};
      
console.log("Object1 has Array? " + !!object1.parentnode.childnode1.length);
console.log("Object2 Has Array? " + !!object2.parentnode.childnode1.length);

console.log("Object1 has Array? " + Array.isArray(object1.parentnode.childnode1));
console.log("Object2 Has Array? " + Array.isArray(object2.parentnode.childnode1));
```

Comment: array is not the only object with a length property

Comment: If the nodes were strings, that would be a problem, but they are objects. To be safe you can use the `Array.isArray()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Though its late. I thought this code would be useful to findout if the child nodes in an object is an array or not
check the following code snippet

```js
var obj = {
    "parentnode": {
        "childnode1": {
            "childnode1.1": {
                "childnode1.1.1": "value here",
            },
        },
    }
}

var count = 0;
checkForArrayObject(obj);
console.log(count);
var obj2={"parentnode":
{
    "childnode1":
    [
        {
            "childnode1.1":
            {
                "childnode1.1.1":"value here",
            },
        },
        {
            "childnode1.2":
            {
                "childnode1.2.1":"value here",
            }
        },
    ]
}};
count=0;
checkForArrayObject(obj2) ;
console.log(count);
function checkForArrayObject(obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Object))
        return count;
    for (var key in obj) {
        var value = obj[key];
        var isArray = obj[key] instanceof Array;

        if (!isArray) {
            checkForArrayObject(value);
        } else
            count++;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps